# Ok so I made this Roblox String Obfuscator but has this error

Tags: lua, obfuscation, roblox

Was wanting the **[Obfuscator](https://pastebin.com/raw/jeb7JjAq)** to Work but Instead Gets the error "Line 5 Expecting Identifier when parsing Expresion" And I don't know what to do, Please Help!

I tried the **Roblox Developer Console**, Was expecting my String Obfuscator to print a String but got the error instead

This is the code

Open link to copy easier

```
local Code = [[
-- Your Lua code here
ABC]]
local function Obfuscate(before, after)
  if string.match(Code, before) then
    Code = Code:gsub(before, after)
  end
  wait(0.01)
end

Obfuscate("%%A", "65 ")
Obfuscate("%%B", "66 ")
Obfuscate("%%C", "67 ")
Obfuscate("%%D", "68 ")
Obfuscate("%%E", "69 ")
Obfuscate("%%F", "70 ")
Obfuscate("%%G", "71 ")
Obfuscate("%%H", "72 ")
Obfuscate("%%I", "73 ")
Obfuscate("%%J", "74 ")
Obfuscate("%%K", "75 ")
Obfuscate("%%L", "76 ")
Obfuscate("%%M", "77 ")
Obfuscate("%%N", "78 ")
Obfuscate("%%O", "79 ")
Obfuscate("%%P", "80 ")
Obfuscate("%%Q", "81 ")
Obfuscate("%%R", "82 ")
Obfuscate("%%S", "83 ")
Obfuscate("%%T", "84 ")
Obfuscate("%%U", "85 ")
Obfuscate("%%V", "86 ")
Obfuscate("%%W", "87 ")
Obfuscate("%%X", "88 ")
Obfuscate("%%Y", "89 ")
Obfuscate("%%Z", "90 ")

Obfuscate("%%a", "97 ")
Obfuscate("%%b", "98 ")
Obfuscate("%%c", "99 ")
Obfuscate("%%d", "100 ")
Obfuscate("%%e", "101 ")
Obfuscate("%%f", "102 ")
Obfuscate("%%g", "103 ")
Obfuscate("%%h", "104 ")
Obfuscate("%%i", "105 ")
Obfuscate("%%j", "106 ")
Obfuscate("%%k", "107 ")
Obfuscate("%%l", "108 ")
Obfuscate("%%m", "109 ")
Obfuscate("%%n", "110 ")
Obfuscate("%%o", "111 ")
Obfuscate("%%p", "112 ")
Obfuscate("%%q", "113 ")
Obfuscate("%%r", "114 ")
Obfuscate("%%s", "115 ")
Obfuscate("%%t", "116 ")
Obfuscate("%%u", "117 ")
Obfuscate("%%v", "118 ")
Obfuscate("%%w", "119 ")
Obfuscate("%%x", "120 ")
Obfuscate("%%y", "121 ")
Obfuscate("%%z", "122 ")

Obfuscate("%%!", "33 ")
Obfuscate("%%\"", "34 ")
Obfuscate("%%#", "35 ")
Obfuscate("%%$", "36 ")
Obfuscate("%%%", "37 ")
Obfuscate("%%&", "38 ")
Obfuscate("%%'", "39 ")
Obfuscate("%%(", "40 ")
Obfuscate("%%)", "41 ")
Obfuscate("%%*", "42 ")
Obfuscate("%%+", "43 ")
Obfuscate("%%,", "44 ")
Obfuscate("%%-", "45 ")
Obfuscate("%%.", "46 ")
Obfuscate("%%/", "47 ")
Obfuscate("%%:", "58 ")
Obfuscate("%%;", "59 ")
Obfuscate("%%<", "60 ")
Obfuscate("%%=", "61 ")
Obfuscate("%%>", "62 ")
Obfuscate("%%?", "63 ")
Obfuscate("%%@", "64 ")
Obfuscate("%%[", "91 ")
Obfuscate("%%\\", "92 ")
Obfuscate("%%]", "93 ")
Obfuscate("%%^", "94 ")
Obfuscate("%%_", "95 ")
Obfuscate("%%`", "96 ")
Obfuscate("%%%{", "123 ")
Obfuscate("%%|", "124 ")
Obfuscate("%%%}", "125 ")
Obfuscate("%%~", "126 ")

Code = Code:gsub(" ", "/")

print(Code)
```

Edit: I realized it was that wait() was uppercase, but now every time I use the **[New Obfuscator](https://pastebin.com/raw/RR6mtmdE)** it prints a string way too long to be for 3 Letters, ABC, wtf is happening

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

Especially this here:

> Some characters, called magic characters, have special meanings when used in a pattern.
>
> - 0 or more repetitions

So when you say `%%*` you escape % and match for "find 0 or more %". Which includes a blank string. So it matches the string of length 0 after each character. It will behave in a similar manner with the other special characters.

I assume you want a single %, to escape the symbol afterwards. In any case, if you just want to convert your string into literal ASCII codes, then this is NOT how to do it.

Comment: No, it was an attempt at a Roblox string obfuscator, it's supposed to get each letter and get its ascii value using Byte, and replace all the letters in the text with their ascii value, making a string obfuscator

Comment: I know but in the current state its wrong (as explained in my answer), irreversible (and thus not obfuscation as it just destroys the code) and intense copy pasta. At the very least use a loop. Also, remember that while this kind of obfuscation is interesting for educational purposes, it won't actually prevent someone from retrieving the code. And more off topic: there is rarely a reason to obfuscate your code in the first place.

Comment: Ok, made a fixed version [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/fJfR2aMs), Thanks Anyways!